# python scrap chrome web-store comment

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, google-reviews

I am trying to scrape reviews from Chrome Web-Store and having a problem with how to distinct between a comment and the replies to the comment.

Below is an example for such HTML, where the user "John Smith" has a comment and a reply.
I am currently using pyppeteer to scrap the content.

I tried `querySelectionAll` for `.ba-bc-Xb-K` and `.ba-bc-Xb` and several other ways, but was not able to clearly make identification

```
<div class="ba-fb">
   <div>
      <div class="ba-bc-Xb">
         <div class="ba-ji-A ba-ua-zl-Xb"><img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=s40-c-k" class="Lg-ee-A-O-xb" alt=""></div>
         <div class="ba-bc-Xb-K">
            <div class="ba-pa">
               <span class="comment-thread-displayname" dir="auto">Lucy</span><span class="ba-Eb-Nf">Jun 26, 2022</span>
               <div class="ba-Eb-N">
                  <div class="rsw-stars" aria-label="1 star">
                     <div class="rsw-starred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <br>
               <div class="ba-Eb-ba" dir="auto">We use this because its easy to hover and text over phone numbers of clients. IT VERY GLITCHY AND CRASHES OFTEN. 90% our of business runs on SMS texting, so I really wish I didn't use this for my company. If any has a better option please let me know!!!! I've been using this for a year and its getting better!!!!!!! AVOID IF YOU CAN!!!! Customer Service is ALSO TERRIBLE!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ba-bc-Xb-cd">
               <div class="bd-Ob Aa">
                  <div class="bd-Ob-L dd">Was this review helpful?</div>
                  <label class="voting-editor-button XzMRXd-sn"><input class="XzMRXd-sn-lc XzMRXd-lc" type="radio" name="vote_AIe9_BGDdh8EqnrWQb-fggox4SOmWi01kdMh4CdLCQD9oHM2uKG-GiDamTukgoJw7LwDNaVtssNY9zUfkPqZTbmL6bYR7YM8Tfa86zq-joAbx8qi5xjbhVjHguGAQoDUMi0YYV_pkFaVKt6ISOsZBGJKlLvhS3uCBg8VrwTO04skZFgbPvYGgPjeQgCKwOz4LyvBPf6dlvKz">Yes</label><label class="voting-editor-button XzMRXd-eb"><input class="XzMRXd-eb-lc XzMRXd-lc" type="radio" name="vote_AIe9_BGDdh8EqnrWQb-fggox4SOmWi01kdMh4CdLCQD9oHM2uKG-GiDamTukgoJw7LwDNaVtssNY9zUfkPqZTbmL6bYR7YM8Tfa86zq-joAbx8qi5xjbhVjHguGAQoDUMi0YYV_pkFaVKt6ISOsZBGJKlLvhS3uCBg8VrwTO04skZFgbPvYGgPjeQgCKwOz4LyvBPf6dlvKz">No</label>
               </div>
               <div class="ba-bc-zb-Pe">
                  <a tabindex="0" class="ba-bc-zb-y z-b-ob-y" role="button">Reply</a><a class="ba-bc-zb-y ba-Eb-xe-ba Pa" role="button" tabindex="0">Delete</a>
                  <div class="ba-bc-zb-y Da-ub"><a tabindex="0" class="Aa Da-ub-y" role="button">Mark as spam or abuse</a></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="yb-ba-Eb-k">
               <div class="Fg-b-ob-k Pa">
                  <textarea class="Fg-b-ob-Gc" rows="5" maxlength="4096" aria-label="Write your reply" placeholder="Write your reply"></textarea>
                  <div class="Od"></div>
                  <div class="Fg-b-ob-Jb-k"><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="g-c g-c-aSvl1d Aa Fg-b-ob-Fb-c"> <input type="button" value="Post" class="g-c g-c-wb Aa Fg-b-ob-qd-c"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Od"></div>
            <div class="Fg-b-ob-fb"></div>
            <div class="Fg-b-mb-Fk Pa"><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="mb-Fk-c">Load more replies</a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="ba-bc-Xb">
         <div class="ba-ji-A ba-ua-zl-Xb"><img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZucpu4S27XT0-ymC2sQo4ML3v0EkQWHfQeW-YO5jyPg=s40-c-k" class="Lg-ee-A-O-xb" alt=""></div>
         <div class="ba-bc-Xb-K">
            <div class="ba-pa">
               <span class="comment-thread-displayname" dir="auto">John Smith</span><span class="ba-Eb-Nf">May 24, 2022</span>
               <div class="ba-Eb-N">
                  <div class="rsw-stars" aria-label="1 star">
                     <div class="rsw-starred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                     <div class="rsw-unstarred" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <br>
               <div class="ba-Eb-ba" dir="auto">Desktop app is interesting and the chrome browser buddy is even better. I wish I was not forced by my company to use the company.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ba-bc-Xb-cd">
               <div class="bd-Ob Aa">
                  <div class="bd-Ob-L dd">Was this review helpful?</div>
                  <label class="voting-editor-button XzMRXd-sn"><input class="XzMRXd-sn-lc XzMRXd-lc" type="radio" name="vote_AIe9_BE0070MjUM89cQCwjN0anL45obXJS3lggtKPsNh1lW8nApB3slGfCkLIRHtWYvTrteJ5Hsx15_Lq2GFBMLLbrKFghCR9XqAfnbN5yIZquqVmHLhEkzLpjGKotj-iX8wKux-rJoLU_8vz3wUKa76z0Ttw8QF2EKBKeT-vhT2WYDm8qPVpdpmgnYnObbYr_aDQlz4P5FD">Yes</label><label class="voting-editor-button XzMRXd-eb"><input class="XzMRXd-eb-lc XzMRXd-lc" type="radio" name="vote_AIe9_BE0070MjUM89cQCwjN0anL45obXJS3lggtKPsNh1lW8nApB3slGfCkLIRHtWYvTrteJ5Hsx15_Lq2GFBMLLbrKFghCR9XqAfnbN5yIZquqVmHLhEkzLpjGKotj-iX8wKux-rJoLU_8vz3wUKa76z0Ttw8QF2EKBKeT-vhT2WYDm8qPVpdpmgnYnObbYr_aDQlz4P5FD">No</label>
               </div>
               <div class="ba-bc-zb-Pe">
                  <a tabindex="0" class="ba-bc-zb-y z-b-ob-y" role="button">Reply</a><a class="ba-bc-zb-y ba-Eb-xe-ba Pa" role="button" tabindex="0">Delete</a>
                  <div class="ba-bc-zb-y Da-ub"><a tabindex="0" class="Aa Da-ub-y" role="button">Mark as spam or abuse</a></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="yb-ba-Eb-k">
               <div class="Fg-b-ob-k Pa">
                  <textarea class="Fg-b-ob-Gc" rows="5" maxlength="4096" aria-label="Write your reply" placeholder="Write your reply"></textarea>
                  <div class="Od"></div>
                  <div class="Fg-b-ob-Jb-k"><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="g-c g-c-aSvl1d Aa Fg-b-ob-Fb-c"> <input type="button" value="Post" class="g-c g-c-wb Aa Fg-b-ob-qd-c"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Od"></div>
            <div class="Fg-b-ob-fb">
               <div>
                  <div class="ba-bc-Xb">
                     <div class="ba-ji-A ba-ua-zl-Xb"><img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZucpu4S27XT0-ymC2sQo4ML3v0EkQWHfQeW-YO5jyPg=s40-c-k" class="Lg-ee-A-O-xb" alt=""></div>
                     <div class="ba-bc-Xb-K">
                        <div class="ba-pa">
                           <span class="comment-thread-displayname" dir="auto">John Smith</span><span class="ba-Eb-Nf">May 24, 2022</span><br>
                           <div class="ba-Eb-ba" dir="auto">I'm happy to chat with the engineering and UX team to tell you exactly how to fix it.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ba-bc-Xb-cd">
                           <div class="bd-Ob Aa">
                              <div class="bd-Ob-L dd">Was this review helpful?</div>
                              <label class="voting-editor-button XzMRXd-sn"><input class="XzMRXd-sn-lc XzMRXd-lc" type="radio" name="vote_AIe9_BFmRFRFwJGRfUDOW8jG3rXnLzUlJu5dFPOnRhcZ3Qpf7k7js81NA_AsDgEfcDAZt0H9yZfs73z4D-hSlo1bxU2QLKaAXG2SMo-85mMfMl_-V6KnhrLHz2FEyGejziQP8UkVi-SsuqBw_lc0GmW9TtC5naBzAp94w9FygzBqeDyguPYXJMc">Yes</label><label class="voting-editor-button XzMRXd-eb"><input class="XzMRXd-eb-lc XzMRXd-lc" type="radio" name="vote_AIe9_BFmRFRFwJGRfUDOW8jG3rXnLzUlJu5dFPOnRhcZ3Qpf7k7js81NA_AsDgEfcDAZt0H9yZfs73z4D-hSlo1bxU2QLKaAXG2SMo-85mMfMl_-V6KnhrLHz2FEyGejziQP8UkVi-SsuqBw_lc0GmW9TtC5naBzAp94w9FygzBqeDyguPYXJMc">No</label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="ba-bc-zb-Pe">
                              <a class="ba-bc-zb-y ba-Eb-xe-ba Pa" role="button" tabindex="0">Delete</a>
                              <div class="ba-bc-zb-y Da-ub"><a tabindex="0" class="Aa Da-ub-y" role="button">Mark as spam or abuse</a></div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Fg-b-mb-Fk Pa"><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="mb-Fk-c">Load more replies</a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally, I'd avoid using these classnames because they change too fast.

I see that comment on this page can be only one level deep. The parent comment has always `<textarea>`, so replies don't have it. You can distinguish parent-reply with this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")  # <-- html_doc is your snippet from the question

out = {}
for div in soup.select("div:has(>.comment-thread-displayname)"):

    # this is a reply:
    if not div.parent.find("textarea"):
        continue

    replies = []
    for s in div.find_next_siblings():
        if (reply := s.find(class_="comment-thread-displayname")) :
            name, date, text = reply.parent.get_text(
                strip=True, separator="\n"
            ).split("\n", maxsplit=2)
            replies.append((name, date, text))

    name, date, text = div.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n").split(
        "\n", maxsplit=2
    )
    out[(name, date, text)] = replies

print(out)
```

Prints dictionary where keys are 3-item tuples of (name, date, text) of parent comment and values are lists of 3-item tuples of replies:

```py
{
    (
        "Lucy",
        "Jun 26, 2022",
        "We use this because its easy to hover and text over phone numbers of clients. IT VERY GLITCHY AND CRASHES OFTEN. 90% our of business runs on SMS texting, so I really wish I didn't use this for my company. If any has a better option please let me know!!!! I've been using this for a year and its getting better!!!!!!! AVOID IF YOU CAN!!!! Customer Service is ALSO TERRIBLE!",
    ): [],
    (
        "John Smith",
        "May 24, 2022",
        "Desktop app is interesting and the chrome browser buddy is even better. I wish I was not forced by my company to use the company.",
    ): [
        (
            "John Smith",
            "May 24, 2022",
            "I'm happy to chat with the engineering and UX team to tell you exactly how to fix it.",
        )
    ],
}
```